# URLSession method not called (didFinishEvents)

Tags: ios, swift

Good afternoon I'm implementing a background file upload using the URLSession.uploadTask method. The file is sent in the background and in the unloaded application, but the methods overridden in delegate 2 are not called.
Namely

```
func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
            let completionHandler = appDelegate.bgSessionCompletionHandler else { return }
            appDelegate.bgSessionCompletionHandler = nil
            completionHandler()
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession 
identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: identifier)
 let backgroundSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration,delegate: 
 self,delegateQueue: nil)
   NotificationService.shared.removeNotification(identifier: "Local Notification")
    bgSessionCompletionHandler = completionHandler
}
```

With what it can be connected?
Complete code:

```
final class NetworkingService: NSObject {
    
    static let shared = NetworkingService()
    
    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    func sendJsonInBackground() {
        NotificationService.shared.createNotification(body: "Отправка отчетов")
        let url = URL(string: "https://localhost:300/upload")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
  
        let fileUrl = findFilePath(withFileName: "file.json", in: .documentDirectory)
        print(fileUrl)
        
        let cfg = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "test.HelloWorld")
    
        cfg.shouldUseExtendedBackgroundIdleMode = true
        
     
        cfg.allowsCellularAccess = true
        
        cfg.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
       
        cfg.waitsForConnectivity = true
        let session = URLSession(configuration: cfg, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: fileUrl!)
        task.earliestBeginDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(10)
        
        
        task.resume() 
    }
    
    
    func createFile(withData data: Data, fileName: String) throws -> URL {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentsDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: fileURL.path, contents: data, attributes: nil)
        print("FileURL: \(fileURL)")
        return fileURL
    }
    
    func findFilePath(withFileName fileName: String, in directory: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory) -> URL? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        // Получаем директорию, в которой будем искать файл
        guard let directoryURL = fileManager.urls(for: directory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
            return nil
        }
        
        // Ищем файлы в указанной директории
        let filePaths = try? fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: directoryURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)

        // Ищем файл с заданным именем в найденных путях
        let matchingFileURL = filePaths?.first { url in
            url.lastPathComponent == fileName
        }
        
        return matchingFileURL
    }


extension NetworkingService: URLSessionTaskDelegate {
   
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        guard let response = task.response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            return
        }
        
        if response.statusCode == 404 {
            NotificationService.shared.createNotification(body: "Отправка отчетов. Ошибка")
        }else {
            let session = URLSession.shared
            //removeFile(withName: "file.json")
            Report.removeAllReports()
            NotificationService.shared.removeNotification(identifier: "Local Notification")
            guard let response = task.response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                return
            }
            for(k,v) in response.allHeaderFields {
                print("\(k) = \(v)")
            }
            let statusCode = response.statusCode
            print("Status Code \(statusCode)")
        }
        
        print("Поток \(Thread.current)")
      
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) {
        let progress = Double(totalBytesSent) / Double(totalBytesExpectedToSend)
        print("progress \(progress)")
    }
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
        // Handle the received data from the task
       
    }

    func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT")
            guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
            let completionHandler = appDelegate.bgSessionCompletionHandler else { return }
            appDelegate.bgSessionCompletionHandler = nil
          
            completionHandler()
        }
    }
}
```

main

```
final class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, URLSessionDelegate {
 
    var bgSessionCompletionHandler:(() ->())?
    
    //Данный метод вызывает только, когда приложение неактивно или работает в фоновом режиме. Вызывается после завершения работы всех фоновых потоков
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
   let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: identifier)
  let backgroundSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration,delegate: self,delegateQueue: nil)
       NotificationService.shared.removeNotification(identifier: "Local Notification")
        bgSessionCompletionHandler = completionHandler
        completionHandler()
    }
```